# Problems getting a new Angular site set up

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, angular6

I've used AngularJS for a bit and wanted to set up a new solution to play with the newest release of Angular.  Every tutorial I've found refers to using ASP.NET Core and then adding the Angular to that project.  From what I understand, best practices would have you keep the web services and the web UI as separate projects, but I have yet to figure out how to get this to work.  So far, I can either get IISExpress to throw a 403 or a 404.  I've tried creating a wwwroot folder within the folder I created for the Angular site and putting an index.html file in there with no success.

It does seem to build the Angular site, but even after updating the angular.json file to point to the wwwroot folder, as I'm assuming that is where IISExpress would be expecting things, nothing ever shows up in that folder that I don't explicitly put there.  I've even tried copying everything from the src folder into the wwwroot folder and that did not make any difference either.

I've read several questions and answers here on StackOverflow, but probably just as many articles stating that there are significant differences between Angular 5 and Angular 6 and a lot of the questions and answers here eventually go to articles about Angular 5.  At this point, I'm not even sure what other information would be helpful to post as there is virtually nothing similar between AngularJS and Angular v6.  All I'm aiming for is a clean, best-practices layout with my repo in one project, the web services in a second project, and the web UI in a third.  If someone can post a link to what I'm looking for or directions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that Angular V2+ is compiled by NPM, so, to run that you have to use npm start in the console.
So, I think you have to deploy your project in some JS files, it's done in the command line.
You could read more about that here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment.
And you will have to deploy your project, and use those files in your ASP.NET project.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like what it will need to be.  Too bad I can't get everything to "just work" within Visual Studio.